# BlackBerry non-wrapping LabelField

Tags: blackberry

I have a label field and 3 edit fields.  I want characters entered in the label field to be on one line.  Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the string using Font.getDefaultFont and call the function [stringWidth](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Font.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29) passing in your label string. If the text is wider then the screen (use [Display.getWidth](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html)), either make the font smaller or trim it to the size.

Another option is to implement your own field but that seems far more work... :)